# How do you completely remove the button border in wpf?

Tags: wpf, button, transparency

I'm trying to create a button that has an image in it and no border - just like the Firefox toolbar buttons before you hover over them and see the full button.

I've tried setting the `BorderBrush` to `Transparent`, `BorderThickness` to `0`, and also tried `BorderBrush="{x:Null}"`, but you can still see the outline of the button.

Comment: alt **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7770227/503501)**

Comment: A borderless button in WPF?!!! What do you think this is, an intuitive UI framework??!

Answer (score 275):

Try this

```
<Button BorderThickness="0"  
    Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" >...
```

Comment: Fantastic! Every other solution I've found is extremely convoluted and involves overriding all styling of the button.

Comment: Unfortunately, it disables the effect of setting `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: It says "x:Static is not supported in a Silverlight project."

Comment: @Cœur the questions specified WPF not Silverlight

Comment: This is turning my button into a toggle button. When I click the button it stays selected until I click another button. How would I stop it from acting like that?

Comment: I'd upvote this twice if I could. Saved me a lot of code to get the look I want.

Comment: This makes my button image gone after i click that. How to resolve this problem??

Answer (score 61):

You may have to change the button template, this will give you a button with no frame what so ever, but also without any press or disabled effect:

```
    <Style x:Key="TransparentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"/>
```

Comment: I don't know why other solutions seems to work at other people. This solution is the only one which can work because the ContentPresenter Border line is also removed! Good work!

Comment: I tried several other solutions, this is the only one works. btw, for newbies, the <style></style> code should be in the header of your xaml like in <Window><Window.Resource><Style>....

Comment: also, there is a typo in the answer: `<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}"/>` should be `<Button Style="{StaticResource TransparentStyle}"/>`

Comment: Worked for me as well, great solution!

Comment: Why there is empty `<ContentPresenter/>` ? What is it for?

Comment: Typo in @Felix comment: should probably be `<Window><Window.Resources><Style>`. Changed in env and that suggestion worked like a charm.

Answer (score 27):

What you have to do is something like this:

```
<Button Name="MyFlatImageButton"
        Background="Transparent"
        BorderBrush="Transparent"
        BorderThickness="0" 
        Padding="-4">
   <Image Source="MyImage.png"/>
</Button>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

**Edit:** Sorry, forgot to mention that if you want to see the button-border when you hover over the image, all you have to do is skip the *Padding="-4"*.

Comment: This works, and this is very nice idea in some cases

Comment: This works perfectly when you want to stretch an image inside a button. Removing the padding lets the image occupy the full button dimensions.

Comment: To remove only the border, `BorderThickness="0"` is enough

Answer (score 24):

I don't know why others haven't pointed out that this question is duplicated with [this one with accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899948/get-rid-of-button-border-in-wpf).

I quote here the solution: You need to override the `ControlTemplate` of the `Button`:

```
<Button Content="save" Name="btnSaveEditedText" 
                Background="Transparent" 
                Foreground="White" 
                FontFamily="Tw Cen MT Condensed" 
                FontSize="30" 
                Margin="-280,0,0,10"
                Width="60"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                BorderThickness="0">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
             <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>  
</Button>
```

Comment: If you don't put any content inside the button it will not respond to clicks. You can fix that by wrapping that ContentPresenter in a Border with a transparent background.  That way you can make a blank/transparent button of any size to place over an image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Hyperlink instead of Button, like this:

```
        <TextBlock>
            <Hyperlink TextDecorations="{x:Null}">
            <Image Width="16"
                   Height="16"
                   Margin="3"
                   Source="/YourProjectName;component/Images/close-small.png" />
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I like this solution. It's a nice trick, gives you a hand cursor on hover and doesn't require to use a custom style.

Answer (score 2):

You may already know that putting your Button inside of a ToolBar gives you this behavior, but if you want something that will work across ALL current themes with any sort of predictability, you'll need to create a new ControlTemplate.

Prashant's solution does not work with a Button not in a toolbar when the Button has focus.  It also doesn't work 100% with the default theme in XP -- you can still see faint gray borders when your container Background is white.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you set both `Background & BorderBrush` by same `brush`

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource marginBackGround}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource marginBackGround}"></Setter>            
 </Style>

<LinearGradientBrush  x:Key="marginBackGround" EndPoint=".5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EE82EE" Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#7B30B6" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#510088" Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#76209B" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#C750B9" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```