# WPF How to enhance or inherit two style for one button

Tags: c#, wpf

Based from this link [How do you completely remove the button border in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995757/how-do-you-completely-remove-the-button-border-in-wpf) The border of button can be remove completely by the following way which works exactly like what I want:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">SomeText</Button>
```

Now I want to define some additional style in my `ResourceDictionary` but I'm not sure how to refer to another style. Usually I refer to custom style thru following way:

```
 <Button Style="someSelfDefinedStyle">SomeText</Button>
```

What can I do if I want to remove the border of button and adding additional styles on top of it?

**Update:**

I've also tried the following way:

```
<Style x:Key="someSelfDefinedStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
    <!--Add additional styling here-->
</Style>
```

And its giving me the below error:

```
'System.Windows.SystemThemeKey' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Style'
```

Comment: Use [snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find the layout, and then you can just copy paste and play around with it ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096/how-to-apply-multiple-styles-in-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`Style.BasedOn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to do that for you:

```
<Style x:Key="AnotherStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource someSelfDefinedStyle}">
    <!--Add additional styling here-->
</Style>
```

---

UPDATE >>>

To use a *default* `Style` as the `BasedOn` property value, you could do this:

```
<Style x:Key="AnotherStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <!--Add additional styling here-->
</Style>
```

However, you cannot do that with your `ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey` as it is an `object` and not a `Style`. The `DefaultStyleKey` for an element is used to lookup the default `Style` for the related element at runtime.

If you to want further styling on your `Button`, you have two options... the first is to define a new [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the `Button` and the second is to put a `Border` element around the `Button` and `Style` that instead:

```
<Border CornerRadius="8" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">SomeText</Button>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

But then of course... you're kind of back where you started.